# How to remove Sender Details in scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

My letter is a bit too long and in order to fit on 1 page I would like to remove the Sender details and the space it takes in the DIn A4 template leaving only the underlined backaddress:

```
\documentclass[
    sender,
    paper=a4,
    version=last,
    fontsize=11pt,
    DIV=13,
    BCOR=0mm]{scrlttr2}
\parskip3mm
\parindent0mm % if you want to have no lineskip
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% Set Font: sans serif Latin Modern
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Set Page layout:
\usepackage{changepage}
%\changepage{text height}{text width}{even-side margin}
%{odd-side margin}{column sep.}
%{topmargin}{headheight}{headsep}{footskip}
\changepage{+3cm}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{-5cm}
\LoadLetterOption{sender}

\begin{document}
% Set Appendix text at very end (dubble point will be set automatically)
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Appendix}
% subject, date, place:
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject: This is an Example}
\setkomavar{date}{den 14. November 2016}
\setkomavar{place}{Bremen}


% Set recipient of letter
\begin{letter}{
    Recipient name \\
    Company SoUndSo\\
    What ever Street\\
    12345 ExampleCity
}
\opening{Dear Recipient}

% Write here your Letter text. You can choose here the language for typeset. ("english", or "ngerman")
\selectlanguage{english}
%\parindent2mm
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,


%\selectlanguage{english}%Choose language for closing text
\closing{kind regards} % use "Mit freundlich Grüßen" i.e. 
\encl{annex}
% end of letter
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

(removing the red box)
[image]

Comment: The  file `sender.lco` is missing. Only a guess: you can add options `pagehead=false`, `pagefoot=false, enlargefirstpage`. You could use lco file `DINmtext`.

Comment: Off topic: Do not change `\parindent` and `\parskip` manually. If do not want to use option `parskip=half-` use `\setparsizes{0pt}{3mm}{0pt plus 1fil}`. In your code you load `sender.lco` twice: as option `sender` and by `\LoadLetterOption`. Additionally I would not use `changepage`.

Comment: Removing the header with the senders information does not enlarge the first letter page. Note that the address field has a fixed position to ensure that a window envelope can be used. If you add `DINmtext` only C6 envelopes can be used.